# How to calculate the mean of row from csv file from nth column?

Tags: shell, perl, unix, awk, text-processing

This may look like a duplicate but I could not solve the issue I'm having.

I'm trying to find the average of each column from a CSV/TSV file the data looks like below:

`input.tsv`

```
ID  source  random  text val1 val2 val3 val4 val330
1   atttt   eeeee   test 0.9  0.5  0.2  0.54 0.89
2   afdg    adfgrg  tf   0.6  0.23 0.5  0.4  0.29
```

output.tsv

```
ID  source  random  text Avg
1   atttt   eeeee   test 0.606
2   afdg    adfgrg  tf   0.404
```

or at least

```
ID  Avg
1   0.606
2   0.404
```

I tried a suggestion from [here](https://www.unix.com/unix-desktop-questions-and-answers/193217-calculate-average-rows-text-file.html)

```
awk 'NR==1{next}
{printf("%s\t", $1
printf("%.2f\n", ($5 + $6 + $7)/3}' input.tsv
```

which threw error.

and

`awk '{ s = 4; for (i = 5; i <= NF; i++) s += $i; print $1, (NF > 1) ? s / (NF - 1) : 0; }' input.tsv`

the below code also threw a syntax error

```
for i in `cat input.tsv` do; VALUES=`echo $i | tr '\t' '\t'`;COUNT=0;SUM=0;typeset -i j;IFS=' ';for j in $VALUES; do;SUM=`expr $SUM + $j`;COUNT=`expr $COUNT + 1`;done;AVG=`expr $SUM / $COUNT`;echo $AVG;done
```

help me resolve the issue to calculate the average of the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be working as expected:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
     (NR==1){ print $1,$2,$3,$4,"Avg:"; next }
     { s=0; for(i=5;i<=NF;++i) s+=$i }
     { print $1,$2,$3,$4, (NF>4 ? s/(NF-4) : s) }' input.tsv
```

or just for the fun of it, if you want to make the for-loop obfuscated:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
     (NR==1){ print $1,$2,$3,$4,"Avg:"; next }
     { for(s=!(i=5);i<=NF;s+=$(i++)) {} }
     { print $1,$2,$3,$4, (NF>4 ? s/(NF-4) : s) }' input.tsv
```

Comment: hi the code worked on the sample file I have taken but on the original file it gave illegal division by zero any idea on that? original file has 189532 columns.

Comment: awk: cmd. line:3: (FILENAME=only_t.tsv FNR=20) fatal: division by zero attempted.

Comment: how to increasethe FNR

Comment: change last NF with `(NF ? NF : 1)`

Comment: awk: cmd. line:3: { print $1,$2,$3,$4,NF>4? s/((NF ? NF : 1)-4):s }
awk: cmd. line:3:                         ^ syntax error

Comment: @NeronLeVelu What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this `awk` script:

```
 awk 'NR>1{
        for(i=5;i<=NF;i++)
          sum+=$i
      }
      {
        print $1,$2,$3,$4,(NF>4&&sum!=""?sum/(NF-4):(NR==1?"Avg":""))
        sum=0
      }' file | column -t
```

The first block gets the sum of all ids starting from the 5th element.

The second block, prints the header line and the average value.

`column -t` displays the result in column.

Comment: Seems like I have an error in when i try to run the command : awk: cmd. line:5: (FILENAME=only_t.tsv FNR=20) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: @PradyumnaSagar This happens on lines where there is no value. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

From you code reference:

```
awk 'NR==1{next}
   {
   # missing the last ). This print the 1st column
   #printf("%s\t", $1
    printf("%s\t", $1 )

   # missing the last ) and average of 3 colum only
   #printf("%.2f\n", ($5 + $6 + $7)/3
    printf("%.2f\n", ($5 + $6 + $7 + $8 + $9) / 5 )
   }' input.tsv
```

Your second code is not easy work with , lot of subshell (backtic) and shell loop but most of all, i think it is made for working with integer value and for full line of value (not 5- > 9). Forget it unless you don't want awk in this case.

for fun

```
awk 'NR==1{
        # Header
        print $0 OFS "Avg"
        Count = NF - 5
        next
        }
        {
        # print each element of the line + sum after col 4
        for( i=Avg=0;i<=NF;i++) {
           if( i >=5 ) Avg+= $i
           printf( "%s ", $i)
           }
        # print average
         printf( "%.2f\n", Avg/Count )
        }
   ' input.tsv
```

Assuming here that it is always counting on the full stack of value, we can change the Count by `(NF - 4)` if less value are on the line and empty are not counting

Comment: I like the way you did `for(i=Avg=0; ...)`. You can get rid of the `if` statement in your for loop if you do `for(Avg=!(i=5); ...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1 { avg = "Avg" }
NR > 1 {
    sum = cnt = 0
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum += $i
        cnt++
    }
    avg = (cnt ? sum / cnt : 0)
}
{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, avg }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ID source random text Avg
1 atttt eeeee test 0.606
2 afdg adfgrg tf 0.404
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> perl -lane '{ $s=0;foreach(@F[4..8]){$s+=$_} $F[4]=$s==0?"Avg":$s/5;print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\t$F[2]\t$F[3]\t$F[4]" } ' input.tsv 
ID      source  random  text    Avg
1       atttt   eeeee   test    0.606
2       afdg    adfgrg  tf      0.404
>
```

Comment: Why not directly print tabs instead of commas in the perl?